# Frame-size does not show up anymore after using grid_forget() - Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, size

I was testing a method to hide and show frames by pressing a button (the buttons will be a menu bar later). So I created this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


win = Tk()

win.geometry("275x350")
win.title("MyProgram")
win.configure(background="white")

frame1 = Frame(win, width=200, height=200)
frame1.grid_propagate(False)
frame2 = Frame(win, width=200, height=200)
frame2.grid_propagate(False)
Label(frame1, text="Hello world", font="20").grid()
Label(frame2, text="Zweiter frame", font="20").grid()

def runGrid(run, destroy):
    run.grid(row=1, column=2)
    destroy.grid_forget()


def run2nd(run, destroy):
    run.grid(row=1, column=2)
    destroy.grid_forget()

Button(win, text="Run", command=lambda:runGrid(frame1, frame2)).grid(row=0, column=0)
Button(win, text="Run 2nd", command=lambda:run2nd(frame2, frame1)).grid(row=0, column=1)


win.mainloop()
```

So here is the problem...
After pressing the first button, the first frame comes up in his wanted size. After pressing the 2nd button, the 2nd frame comes up in his wanted size. But when you press the first button again (after pressing both buttons once before) then the frame is just showing up like `grid_propagate` was removed from the code (the frame is just as big as the label in it). Can someone explain me the fault in my code which is causing the problem?

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an other way to get what I want:

By simply using `grid_remove()` instead of using `grid_forget()` it is working.
But I still hope someone can answer my question because it really should work with `grid_forget()` as well I think.

Comment: No, it does'nt work with `grid_forget()` that is why `grid_remove()` exists.